# Flutter Firebase In-App Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have just seen on Firebase that a new feature has been released called In-App Messaging. Is there already an idea somewhere how to get this to work with Flutter?

Comment: The Flutter In-App Messaging plugin is now available: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_in_app_messaging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use it with flutter yet. A flutter plugin needs to be created to be able to use the [`In-App Messaging API`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started)

You can check all flutter plugins that enable Flutter apps to use one or more Firebase services here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

---

### EDIT

The flutter in-app messaging plugin is now available!
You can find more information about in the following link:

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_in_app_messaging

Comment: Will keep my eyes open for the flutter plugin then

Comment: but a people here say he can use inapp messaging, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893994/flutter-firebase-in-app-messaging/56676344#56676344

Comment: You can use `in app messaging` but you need to configure it on your own in the `build.gradle` for android and in the `pod file` for ios. For example if you check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android, then using the firebase console you can send a message @anunixercoder

Comment: What you *cannot* do is this https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior you cant modify what happens if the users interacts with the message @anunixercoder

Comment: @anunixercoder in the end the in app message is created in the firebase console, so by connecting your app to the console and adding firebase in buiild.gradle or pod file you can send an in app message but again as I said you cannot modify the behaviour https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior

Comment: In app messaging is now available in flutter check out the plugin https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_in_app_messaging