# How to get "Apps Instance Id" in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-in-app-messaging

i want to setup **firebase inapp messaging** on my flutter apps.

first, it need `FirebaseInstanceId` as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android#get_your_apps_instance_id), so i can test send message to my device.

However the document does not tell more detail how to get it on Android, especially on flutter.

any idea ?

Note : someone has claimed that he can use **inapp-messaging** in flutter, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893994/flutter-firebase-in-app-messaging/56676344#56676344)

Thank you in Advance...

Comment: Two great videos, [Raja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfTrbKtnvTo) and [Fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TSm2YGBT1s)

Comment: I found the instance Id on Android using logcat. Easiest solution

Answer (score 20):

The Firebase Instance ID can be fetched using [-instanceIDWithHandler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/FIRInstanceID#-instanceidwithhandler:) on iOS or [getInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid-) on Android.

At the time of writing, I am not aware of a standalone plugin that does this, meaning that you have two options:

- Write your own plugin that wraps the native implementations of those methods
- Use the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) Flutter plugin that happens to expose the Instance ID via its getToken() method

If you go the firebase_messaging route (mind you, it means you're adding another dependency), you can do something like this:

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

and then, somewhere in your code:

```
var token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
print("Instance ID: $token");
```

**Update**

When you call get token, you get something in the following format: *NNNNNNN:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM*. Take only the first part before the colon (*NNNNNNNN*) - this is the instance ID you need to test your In-App Messaging campaign.

Comment: i try to input `instance_id` / `token` that i got from `_firebaseMessaging.getToken()`, but i got error in firebase console : `Invalid format. Please check the docs for retrieving the instance ID.` Any Idea ?

Comment: When you call get token, you get something in the following format: NNNNNNN:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM.

Take only the first part before the colon (NNNNNNNN) - this is the instance ID you need to test your In-App Messaging campaign.

Comment: As per October/2019 it's necessary to pass full token, INCLUDING content after colon

Comment: Where is it actually documented that the first part of the token is in fact the stable instance id?

Comment: You are a life saver. For some reason, using the official method is not showing the instance Id in console. This method works. I wonder why it is not documented though

Answer (score 5):

You can run this in your terminal.

```
adb logcat | grep 'InAppMessaging'
```

> 02-26 23:47:44.835 28379 28379 I FIAM.Headless: Starting
> InAppMessaging runtime with Installation ID dTEmOkEwRzC_xiO8YNPXs0

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `FirebaseInstanceId` you need to implement the Firebase In-App messaging SDK and make sure your app connects to Firebase.

Once the app is connected to Firebase it will add the `FirebaseInstanceId` to the Android log once the App is run.

In the article you linked Google explains that you can find the `FirebaseInstanceId` by looking in the log for the string `I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Instance ID <YOUR_APP_ID>`.

If you are using Android Studio you should be able to use the `logcat` window to browse the logs of the device (while debugging the App). The `logcat` window will also allow you to search and filter the logs so it should be relative easy to find the mentioned string.

So in short (in Android Studio):

1. Implement the Firebase In-App messaging SDK in your App;
2. Start debugging the App (preferably on a real Android device);
3. While debugging open the `Logcat` window;
4. Search the logs for the string `I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Instance ID`;
5. The FirebaseInstanceId should be listed directly after the string.

Comment: I'm using VSCODE, where will I find this?

Comment: Not sure if it will show up in the "DEBUG CONSOLE" window. Otherwise you can always fallback on the shell command as mentioned by @prisar: `adb logcat | grep 'InAppMessaging'` or use the code example mentioned by @david-airapetyan.

Answer (score 0):

Using [flutterfire_installations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_installations), you can get:

- Installation ID:

  ```dart
  String id = await FirebaseAppInstallations.instance.getId();
  ```
- Authentication token:

  ```dart
  String token = await FirebaseAppInstallations.instance.getToken();
  ```

Comment: old method, does not work anymore