# Can't get Firebase token on real Android device with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

My code can get token Firebase on Emulator Android and real Android device (Xiaomi Redmi 6, SKD: 28).

But I run on real Android device (PAD device) with info:

- Board: msm8953
- Brand: PAD
- Device: HSSDM450QC
- Display: OPM1.171019.019 release-keys
- Hardware: qcom
- id: OPM1.171019.019
- model: PAD
- product: PAD
- Android version: 8.1.0 (SDK: 27)

The Android device can't get Firebase Token.

```html
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751): getToken, error fetching instanceID: 
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751): java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.handleResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.1:7)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(Unknown Source:8)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.then(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseIidExecutors$$Lambda$0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:15)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Unknown Source:8)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:9)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:7)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:45)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzi.handleMessage(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6606)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751): getToken, error fetching instanceID: 
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751): java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.handleResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.1:7)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(Unknown Source:8)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.then(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseIidExecutors$$Lambda$0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:15)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Unknown Source:8)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:9)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:7)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:45)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzi.handleMessage(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6606)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(22751):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

with Code:

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  assert(token != null, 'Token is null');
  print('Push Messaging token: $token');
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767920/how-to-get-apps-instance-id-in-flutter

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529977/firebase-token-error-too-many-registrations 
I think my device is a real device which has been customized with a CLONE image of the system partition, CLONED from a different device. But has ideas fix it?